# Xamarin - ios xaml Preview fail with monotouch error

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I am experimenting a fail on xaml preview on my Xamarin project on VisualStudio for MAC 7.6.4.
After some update, xaml no render yet the preview showing a System.NullReferenceaException as showed in the picture.

Any help about tht issue?
[image]

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I don not think is a code error. Android  preview work and porject compile and work on both platform

Comment: You can delete the folder  bin and obj  under the forms project , and rebuild the project again